# Is it safe to use Dynamic class creation at runtime? Apple will allow to publish it in appstore?

Tags: xamarin.ios, interpreter, reflection.emit, activator

We did Dynamic Class Creation at runtime using reflection and Activator.CreateInstance() method.

We followed the below link for VM part creation
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/introducing-xamarin-ios-interpreter/

For UI creation, we used loadfromxaml()

We test our app with adhoc profile. Its works fine.

Apple will allow to publish it appstore? Are any restriction is there for dynamic creation of objects?

Answer (score 0):

There are many limitations in Xamarin.iOS, since the iOS kernel prevents applications from dynamically generating code, Xamarin.iOS does not support any form of dynamic code generation.

1.The System.Reflection.Emit is not available.

2.No support for System.Runtime.Remoting.

3.No support for creating types dynamically (no Type.GetType ("MyType`1")), although looking up existing types (Type.GetType ("System.String") for example, works just fine).

4.Reverse callbacks must be registered with the runtime at compile time.

More details can be found in the document：[Limitations of Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations)